Finding a function when passing another function to it
If I got a function $f(x)$, and I want to get the definition of this function, in trying to do that, I got this (for example) :
$\displaystyle f\left(e^x+2x-\frac{x}{x^2-2x+2}\right)=2x+1$
How to find $f(x)$ here in such a situation?

Let $h(x)=e^x+2x-\frac{x}{x^2-2x+2}$ meaning you have $f(h(x))=2x+1$. Now let $t=h(x)$ meaning $x=h^{-1}(t)$. Substitute both of these to your original formula and you get $f(t)=2h^{-1}(t)+1$. If you can somehow find the inverse of $h(x)$ you have your answer.
However, the inner function $h(x)$ you have here seems a bit complicated and I don't know to find the inverse in this particular case. But when you can find the inverse, the rest is simple.
EDIT: Here's another way to look at it. Let $g(x)=2x+1$. Now the problem is finding $f$ when $f\circ h=g$. It should be immediately obvious that $f=g\circ h^{-1}$.

Thanks ! The example I gave is complex, I know, but I wanted to know the general rule, thanks again !

@hasandarwish No problem. I added an edit which gives a slightly different way to look at the problem.
